Unused pins on static drive LCD
I'm looking at using a Lumex S3X1C50TR in an upcoming project. This is a static drive, 7-segment, 3.5 digit LCD display. It's my understanding that "static" drive LCDs require an AC square wave to the backplane pin (seems to be named COM on this datasheet?), with an in-phase signal to any segment that is "off", and out-of-phase for segments that are "on". I have a driver IC that will handle those gory details.
But this particular display has a few segments I will never use (for example: "lo bat", as my circuit is not using batteries). Can I leave those pins unconnected, or should I connect them to the backplane signal so they'll always be in-phase?
A follow-up question: This particular display has two pins labeled COM - should they both be connected to the backplane signal, or will one suffice?

Does the answer in Is it OK to connect not used segments of an LCD display to the backplane pin? help?

Thanks! This, combined with Justme's answer below, answered all my questions =)

To best make sure the unused symbols are off, either connect them to the common, or if you have enough pins on your driver, connect it to a signal you keep off. This way all segments are driven identically and maybe you can use the unused symbols for debugging.
The display is not multiplexed but it has two backplane contacts. The datasheet does not say if these are two separate connections to a single backplane or is the backplane split into two so it needs two pins.
In any way, best to drive both pins with the same signal, as the conductive paths on glass are not very good conductors, so it may improve the driving of the display.

Thanks! That makes sense =)
